# Conditional expectation of geometrically distributed random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Given $Y$ as a geometrically distributed random variable with $p\in (0,1)$, what is $E[Y|Y\geq 10]?$

I got:$$E(Y|Y\geq 10)=\frac{E(\mathbf{1}_{Y\geq 10}Y)}{P(Y\geq 10)}=\frac{E(\mathbf{1}_{Y\geq 10}Y)}{1-P(Y\leq 9)}=\frac{E(\mathbf{1}_{Y\geq 10}Y)}{(1-p)^9}$$ But what is $E(\mathbf{1}_{Y\geq 10}Y)$ equal to?

Comment: $E[1_{Y \ge 10} Y] = \sum_y 1_{y \ge 10} y P(Y=y) = \sum_{y \ge 10} yP(Y=y)$. II think you have some typos when computing $P(Y \ge 10)$ though. Also please state which type of geometric distribution you are using: there is one that counts number of *trials* until (and including) the first success, and a different one that counts number of *failures* before the first success.

Comment: The first one: number of trials until (and including) the first success.

Comment: $P(Y\geq 10)=1-P(Y\leq 9)=1-(1-(1-p)^9))=(1-p)^9$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E[1_{Y \ge 10} Y] = \sum_{y \ge 10} yp(1-p)^{y-1}$$
$$(1-p) E[1_{Y \ge 10} Y] = \sum_{y \ge 11} (y-1)p(1-p)^{y-1}$$
Subtracting the two equations yields
$$pE[1_{Y \ge 10} Y] = 10p(1-p)^9 + p\sum_{y \ge 11}(1-p)^{y-1} = 10p(1-p)^9 + (1-p)^{10}
= (1-p)^9 (9p+1)$$
and thus
$$E[1_{Y \ge 10} Y] = \frac{(1-p)^9 (9p+1)}{p}.$$
Dividing by $(1-p)^9$ yields $E[Y \mid Y \ge 10] = \frac{9p+1}{p} = 9 + \frac{1}{p}$.

---

If you know the "memorylessness" property of the Geometric distribution, you can arrive at the answer much quicker by noting that the conditional distribution of $Y \mid \{Y \ge 10\}$ is the same as the distribution of $Y + 9$, so $E[Y \mid Y \ge 10] = E[Y] + 9 = \frac{1}{p} + 9$.

Comment: Hey, could you please elaborate how you subtracted the two lines and got $(1-p)^9(9p+1)$?

Comment: @Analysis The first step is $\sum_{y \ge 10} f(y) - \sum_{y \ge 11} g(y) = f(10) + \sum_{y \ge 11} (f(y) - g(y))$. Then I sum the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula).

Comment: Thank you very much!